# Vendoring proto dependencies

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

Right now it seems that there is no way to vendor a `proto_library`. When I add `proto_library` rules in [here](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/tree/master/third_party/googleapis), the import statements fail when I'm trying to import "google/api/annotations.proto". I would expect there to be something like a `proto_path` or `strip_prefix` attribute available on `proto_library` but nothing like that seems to exist. Does anyone have any experience with vendoring protos in Bazel?